# dialog menu to display files, select one of them and then able to delete it

Tags: shell-script, files, dialog

I want to be able to display files under a given directory, then select one of the files and be able to delete it.

Here's what I've found so far. Can anybody help?

```
let i=0 # define counting variable
W=() # define working array
while read -r line; do # process file by file
    let i=$i+1
    W+=($i "$line")
done < <( ls -1 /home/admin/Desktop )
FILE=$(dialog --title "List file of directory /home" --menu "Chose one" 24 80 17 "${W[@]}" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3) # show dialog and store output
clear
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then # Exit with OK
    readlink -f $(ls -1 /home | sed -n "`echo "$FILE p" | sed 's/ //'`")
fi
```

Comment: `dialog` has a `-fselect` option for selecting files, which should help you.

Answer (score 0):

The script uses the return-value from `dialog` to select an item from a list of files (or directories) in a given source directory.

The problem with the bash script is that it uses *two different directory values*:

```
let i=0 # define counting variable
W=() # define working array
while read -r line; do # process file by file
    let i=$i+1
    W+=($i "$line")
done < <( ls -1 /home/admin/Desktop )
FILE=$(dialog --title "List file of directory /home" --menu "Chose one" 24 80 17 "${W[@]}" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3) # show dialog and store output
clear
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then # Exit with OK
    readlink -f $(ls -1 /home | sed -n "`echo "$FILE p" | sed 's/ //'`")
fi
```

Those are **`/home/admin/Desktop`** and **`/home`**.  The usual practice would make those a symbol (i.e., a variable), and eliminate the inconsistency:

```
#!/bin/bash
source=/home/admin/desktop 
let i=0 # define counting variable
W=() # define working array
while read -r line; do # process file by file
    let i=$i+1
    W+=($i "$line")
done < <( ls -1 $source )
FILE=$(dialog --title "List file of directory $source" --menu "Chose one" 24 80 17 "${W[@]}" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3) # show dialog and store output
clear
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then # Exit with OK
    readlink -f $source/$(ls -1 $source | sed -n "`echo "$FILE p" | sed 's/ //'`")
fi
```

Having done that, the result from `readlink` would be usable.

The script with that fix is incomplete:

- it does not actually remove a file
- it does not check if the item to remove is a file or a directory
- using the output of `ls` (twice!) is not the best way to obtain a listing